# How can i split the address

Tags: split

I need to split the address using script. This is my input addresses

1 Avenue Descartes 92350 Le Plessis-Robinson FRANCE

**My output like below:**

```
1
Avenue Descartes
92350 
Le Plessis-Robinson 
FRANCE
```

Comment: 1
Avenue Descartes
92350 
Le Plessis-Robinson 
FRANCE

Comment: Is it a native address field

Comment: @ Ashwani  this is my client address I need to split this how can I do this

Comment: Is is a custom field or the standard address field on Contact?

Comment: @BarCotter thanks for your reply this is custom field.

Comment: So you have a string that you want to split. Whats the criteria for splitting it? Can you provide some more examples?

Comment: @BarCotter Actully we want split into full address to placed into proper address field like street, city, postal code,country

Comment: You need to define the requirements for splitting the address.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27722/discussion-between-nikitha-and-barcotter).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a specific identifier to split the custom address field into address components and store in proper address fields.

You should determine the identifier in your custom address field. Usually the identifier will be Comma(,).

Custom Address Field value = 1,Avenue Descartes,92350,Le Plessis-Robinson,FRANCE

In your apex method,

```
List<String> lstStringAddress = object.customField__c.split(',');
object.AddressField1 = lstStringAddress[0];
object.AddressField2 = lstStringAddress[1];
object.AddressField3 = lstStringAddress[2];
object.AddressField4 = lstStringAddress[3];
object.AddressField5 = lstStringAddress[4];
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: @ Vigneshwaran thanks for your reply some times I get different address it display the proper address field?

Comment: If the order is not changed, it will display the correct address after split. Door Number, Street, ZipCode, State, Country should be the order.

Comment: I got your point but I splites with (,):1, Avenue, Descartes, 92350, Le, Plessis-Robinson, FRANCE>How can I map exactly for that address

Comment: If this kind of address comes, you can't even determine which one is street, which is state. So first you need discuss to come into a conclusion of how the address will be present and do your split according. No other options or solutions am aware of.

Comment: is there any other solution?

Comment: @nikitha You could try sending the address to google geocoding/mapping services.   It will send back a nromalized address, from which you can then select the various address parts (Street, Door Number, PostalCode, etc.).  However, you may run into issues with your input string since there is no idenifiable segmentation.  Also, this will require use of webservice callouts and a susbscription to Google.    If this is a one-time deal, I'm certain there are companies which can standardize your address data for import.